# Running apk on samsung nexus s wont respond

Tags: android

I made an easy apk in sdk,the emulator is good,everything is working ,done the export and when trying to run the apk on my device samsung nexus s it wont even show it ,i tryed do DL it from mail and it says "it camed to a error by analayzing " ,any hints or help how to ix this problem?

Comment: What message did you receive from ADB when you installed the APK? Sometimes you have to delete the old APK before installing the new APK.

Comment: is your error message typed in the question is exactly correct?

Comment: Can you connect the phone to a computer and enable USB debugging and transfer it that way rather than over mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using eclipse then select "Project --> Clean" option. 
Then rebuild the apk file. Sometimes cleaning will resolve the problem.

Comment: oh,today in the morrning i got it... sorry for the dumb question but i transfered wrong file on my device and thats why it coudnt run -_-,tnx for help.

Comment: Glad you are able to find the root cause. No one else other than you can find this problem :)